# pandas np.where based on mulitindex level

Tags: pandas, indexing, multi-index

I have a Dataframe with MultiIndex. The two Levels are 'Nr' and 'Price'. Is it possible to use np.where on Index Level 1 ('Price') to create a new column ('ZZ')?

'ZZ' should be calculated by column 'first' multiplicated by 2, if Level 1 ('Price') is equal to 'x'.

```
import pandas as pd
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['s1', 's2','s3'],['x','y']])
df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4,5,6],index, columns=['first'] )
df.index.names = ['Nr', 'Price']
df
```

I tried:

```
df['ZZ'] = np.where(df['Price']=='x',df['0']*2,np.nan)
```

I obtain:

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `get_level_values`

```
np.where(df.index.get_level_values(1)=='x', df['first']*2, np.nan)
array([ 2., nan,  6., nan, 10., nan])
#df['ZZ'] = np.where(df.index.get_level_values(1)=='x', df['first']*2, np.nan)
```